# How to dump data from python as JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a python program that can extract information from HTML files but I would like it dumped as a json file.

```
import glob
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for filename in glob.iglob('*.html'):
    with open(filename) as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

        price = soup.findAll('span', {"class":'bb_price'})
        title = soup.find("span", id="btAsinTitle")
        author = title.find_next("a", href=True)
        isbn = soup.find('b', text='ISBN-10:').next_sibling
        weight = soup.find('b', text='Shipping Weight:').next_sibling

        print {'title': title.get_text(),
               'author': author.get_text(),
               'isbn': isbn,
               'weight': weight,
               'price': price}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of typical input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
import glob
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main():
    data = []
    for filename in glob.iglob('*.html'):
        with open(filename) as f:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

            title = soup.find("span", id="btAsinTitle")
            data.append({
                "title":  title.get_text(),
                "author": title.find_next("a", href=True).get_text(),
                "isbn":   soup.find('b', text='ISBN-10:').next_sibling,
                "weight": soup.find('b', text='Shipping Weight:').next_sibling,
                "price":  soup.findAll('span', {"class":'bb_price'})
            })

    with open("my_output.json", "w") as outf:
        json.dump(data, outf)

main()
```

Comment: TypeError: <span class="bb_price">
$16.89      </span> is not JSON serializable ... do you know what this means?

Comment: json doesn't know how to store objects; it expects a string, int, float, list, or dict. It looks like `"price"` is a `span` object; try `"price": soup.findAll('span', {"class":'bb_price'}).get_text()` instead.

Comment: Brothwell thats awesome thank you. I changed it to '"price":  soup.find('span', {"class":'bb_price'}).get_text()'. It dumps it to a json file but entirely in one line. Do you know how I can go about setting it up in proper hierarchy?

Comment: You can ask it to pretty-print like `json.dump(data, outf, indent=1)`

Answer (score 3):

```
with open(output_filename, 'w') as f
    json.dump(data, f)
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump